# Using rsync with Middleman

Tags: web-deployment, rsync, middleman

I am fairly new to Middleman and I would like to transfer my files with rsync. I have paswordless SSH access but every time I try do `middleman deploy` it asks me for a password. And if I type in cPanel password it says it isn't right and I can't rsync it.

I'm using [this](https://github.com/middleman-contrib/middleman-deploy) gem. It says:

```
activate :deploy do |deploy|
  deploy.deploy_method = :rsync
  deploy.host          = 'www.mysite.com'
  deploy.path          = '/'
end
```

What am I missing here? FYI I'm using Namecheap and I tried to use their port.

Answer (score 0):

If your username on the server is different to your username on your local machine, you might need to set `deploy.user` in your `config.rb` to log in.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it's better to set up Middleman deployments using [Rake](https://github.com/ruby/rake) to configure shell commands. For me, the `middleman-deploy` gem didn't abstract away enough complexity to make it worth it to configure.

If you set up your local SSH environment to connect to your server without the use of a password it makes this especially quick. I set up a `rakefile` that looks like this:

```
# rakefile
server      = "webserver.someurl.com"
remote_path = "/srv/html/"
permissions = "--chmod=Du=rwx,Dg=rx,Do=rx,Fu=rw,Fg=r,Fo=r"
task :deploy do
  sh "middleman build"
  sh "rsync -rDv build/ #{server}:#{remote_path} --delete #{permissions}"
end
```

Then I can run my deployment with `rake deploy`.

There's more detail in my [Boilerplate Middleman](https://github.com/ryanburnette/boilerplate-middleman) project if you want to check it out.